# I want to make a bottom bar

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I want to make lower under the bar.But I don't know how to make. Press the lower bar to help me seyeo can get a page, I want I want to make.And I want to put the image that I want in the bottom bar Tell me what to do first I need your help I searched hard on Google, but there is no code similar to mine, so I keep getting it wrong or weird

```
import React, { useRef, useState, useCallback, useEffect } from 'react';
import {
  View,
 BackHandler,
 Platform,
 StyleSheet,
 ActivityIndicator,
} from 'react-native';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';
import { Image } from "react-native";
const DELAY_BEFORE_WEBVIEW = 10; // <--- seconds before webview load

export default function App() {
  // ref
  const webView = useRef();

 const [canGoBack, setCanGoBack] = useState(false);

  const handleBack = useCallback(() => {
    if (canGoBack && webView.current) {
      webView.current.goBack();
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }, [canGoBack]);

  // effects
  useEffect(() => {
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', handleBack);
    return () => {
      BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', handleBack);
    };
 }, [handleBack]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }, 1000 * DELAY_BEFORE_WEBVIEW);
  }, []);

  // states
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <WebView
        ref={webView}
        source={{ uri: 'https://www.talesrunnerbestguild.co.kr/' }}
        style={styles.webView}
        onLoadProgress={(event) => setCanGoBack(event.nativeEvent.canGoBack)}
      />
      {isLoading && <CenterLoader />}
    </View>
  );
}

const CenterLoader = () => (
  <View style={styles.loaderContainer}> 
       <Image source={require('/workspace/talesrunner23/assets/js34.png/')} 
        style={{height:115,width:90}}/>
   </View>
);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: { flex: 1 },
  loaderContainer: {
   flex: 1,
   justifyContent: 'center',
   alignItems: 'center',
   position: 'absolute',
   width: '100%',
   height: '100%',
   backgroundColor:'white' // <-- comment this to show webview while loading
},
  webView:
    Platform.OS === 'ios'
      ? { marginTop: 30, marginBottom: 40 }
     : { marginTop: 30 },
});
```

Comment: You should not just paste all the code here. And should explain things better. I can't understand what you really want to achive.

Comment: Do you want this? https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator/

Comment: yes l want  this